# Workstation restarts automatically

Tags: desktop, workstation

I have workstation with Asus Rog strix B450 F motherboard and got it replaced recently. I had 2 rams DDR4 where I found that one of the DIMM might be faulty as the workstation when powered on did not displayed anything on the monitor.

With one ram module, the workstation boots and displays properly, but sometimes it automatically turns off and restarts again. I see that there is white LED light blinking on the motherboard which I understood that this white LED light represent issue with display. I recently got new Nvidia GT 730 adapter fitted on the motherboard where the monitor is connected. I am curious to understand if the monitor has any problem / issue, will that cause any desktop to restart automatically? Monitor is dell. White LED light represents issue with VGA based on Asus Q LED signals.

Comment: you mixed things up. please clarify the issues, most modern mb have boot code number indicated by using led numbers and letters. in case of windows check eventviewer

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: your motherboard got replaced? And a graphics card added? Then in theory it could be either. But the graphics card should not influence memory, while I can see the reverse happening. So test the RAM first.  One DIMM in the  right socket (as should be in the motherboard manual). Then the other DIMM in the same memory socket.  If both DIMMs are ok there should be no difference.